# Rendering Parameters values being null after sitecore upgrade

Tags: sxa, glass-mapper, upgrade, caching

We have upgrade Sitecore solution from 9.1 to 10.11, as part of upgradation we had upgraded Sitecore databases and solution. We have around 80 plus sites and we are using sxa.

Let me describe about my issue , we have header logo component being used across all the sites, the problem here this header component is working for few sites and few sites its not. When keep debug on not working sites , getting returning parameter value set to null because of this the component is not rendered.

When go to final layout section of the component and make small change on it and then component is rendering fine , we are assuming this could be cache issue. We have developed all the components using glass mapper.

Comment: "make small change on it and then component is rendering fine" - any kind of change or a particular one? Did you try to clear all your caches? All upgrade steps have been run without issues? What is the point of using Glass Mapper nowadays?

Comment: make small change on it and then component is rendering fine-any kind of change or a particular one?-> If change any rendering parameter its start to work.
Did you try to clear all your cache->Cleared Sitecore cache and browser cache also.
All upgrade steps have been run without issues? - Upgraded successfully with out any issue
What is the point of using Glass Mapper nowadays? - We were using Glass Mapper  on lower on lower version same thing we brought here.

Comment: In addition to above comment , we are experiencing this  issue on custom components only not on sxa components.